# TinyMCE Toolbar Missing After Plone 4.3 Upgrade

Tags: plone

I upgrade a Plone site from 4.2 to 4.3. The upgrade steps are basically:

1. running install.sh to have a 4.3 environment
2. copy Data.fs to var/filestorage and custom dexterity package to src
3. running upgrade in ZMI

Everything seems fine. But when I add/edit Page items, TinyMCE toolbar is missing for the body field. Only showing a Text Format dropdown. Note: I do see the toolbar trying to render (first 2 icons appear), but fail and disappear.

What am I missing? Any hints?

[image]

Comment: References: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095303/plone-4-3-default-editor-isnt-showing-up

Comment: And this one, relating to combined languages, as you mentioned below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174270/using-linguaplone-in-plone-4-the-tinymce-editor-is-not-showing-up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No definitive answers, but a few suggestions. I have 9 plone sites all running the same version of Plone (4.2) and have some where TinyMCE works flawlessly, and others where I can't make it work at all.

- Check `/portal_javascripts` and make sure that you have ++resource++plone.app.jquery.js (I think you also need jquery-integration.js and ++resource++plone.app.jquerytools.js, but I may be wrong about those), as well as tiny_mce.js and tiny_mce_init.js).
- check `/portal_kss` and ensure you have ++resource++tinymce.kss/tinymce.kss
- check `/portal_css` for ++resource++tinymce.stylesheets/tinymce.css

I saw your edit about the toolbar beginning to display after I posted this response. You really need to use the development tools for your browser-of-choice (e.g. Firebug) and look at the console. If it starts to display and then fails to finish, there's sure to be an error in the console log.

Comment: I compare between a fresh and upgraded 4.3 instances, and find: at /portal_javascripts, ++resource++plone.app.jquery.js bundle is originally set as `default`, I then change it to `jquery`. No luck.

Comment: For /portal_kss, I find it removed after upgrade. Does the missing ++resource++tinymce.kss/tinymce.kss relate to the toolbar issue? Since KSS is removed by Plone 4.3, I'd expect /portal_kss removal is normal.

Comment: @marr Without tinymce.kss I didn't get a toolbar - but as I said, it's Plone 4.2.  In any case, I really think you need to check the javascript console, because _starting_ to build the toolbar but not completing it sounds like a JS bug.

Comment: Thanks! I should consult experts around me about the javascript console. On another case, upgrade from 4.2.2 to 4.3.0, everything seems fine, including TinyMCE working perfectly. So this issue might relate to some specific add-on products.

Comment: I'm _sure_ you're right about add-ons. I have no problems with sites without add-ons, or some sites with a few, but no end of problems with the site that has the most add-ons. Unfortunately it's too many add-ons for it to be obvious which one is the problem.

Comment: Here is the package list I think possibly related from src directory, hope it helpful for someone: collective.disqus collective.geo.* my.custom.theme

@Auspex If any of the above add-ons happens to be the same with yours, then we might get closer to the possible issue :)

Comment: Another hint: TinyMCE Toolbar JS uses language codes in 2-letter format (like zh or tw, not zh-tw). At least this is bothering me, a Traditional Chinese (zh-tw) user. A ticket is issued at https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13615

Comment: collective.geo would be a possibility.

Answer (score 3):

Check to see whether you have outstanding upgrades to the `Products.TinyMCE:TinyMCE` profile in Upgrades in portal_setup via the ZMI. If there are any, run them and restart your Plone instance.

I had the same issue with the same version upgrades and there were outstanding upgrades. They must have been missed somehow, presumably a bug in the Plone upgrade process from 4.2.5 to 4.3.4.

Comment: Have you reported this issue?

Comment: @hvelarde This issue only happened to me once out of several sites, so I presumed it was an isolated incident.  Certain sites I have had ``Products.TinyMCE`` upgraded independently of Plone at times (to bring in bug fixes), so this might have been the reason.  If I see this issue again, I'll create a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I just ran into this issue in an upgrade from 4.1 to 4.3.14.

In my case, the problem was that the site uses the Plone Classic skin instead of Sunburst.  The Classic skin for some reason did not have the `tinymce` layer registered.  The giveaway was that `jquery.tinymce.js` was registered in `portal_javascripts`, but marked in orange as **(resource not found or not accessible)**.  I grepped the buildout eggs and realized that `jquery.tinymce.js` lives in a skin layer of `Products.TinyMCE-1.3.26`.  From there it was easy to figure out why it was not found.