# Plone 4.3 default editor isn't showing up

Tags: tinymce, plone

I have a Plone 4.3 site that was a migration from a Plone 2.5 site. It had been working fine, but for some reason the default editor that shows up when editing any page or content item is the straight HTML view.

I've tested it in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari — all shows up the same. The drop down menu above the editing box shows these options:

[image: Editor options]

I've also tried switching the "Default editor" both in the **Site setup > Editing Control Panel** and also through the **ZMI > portal_properties > site_properties > available_editors** but no dice. The options there are None, Kupu, and TinyMCE.

There are two other Plone sites on this same instance (not migrations though, they started as Plone 4.3 sites) and their editors show up like normal.

Any thoughts? I'm at a loss, except to maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling TinyMCE through buildout, but I'm wary of whether or not that might break something else, especially if it breaks the other two sites.

Comment: Experienced the same after P4.1-to-P4.3-upgrade but can't figure out what happended. Setting users' editor-prefs doesn't help. Suspect JS-conflict of 3rd-party. Creating a new site with same add-ons installed, but cannot reproduce. Can you reproduce the error like this?

Comment: Any errors in firebug?

Comment: @aclark: No, nothing.

Comment: References: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485452/tinymce-toolbar-missing-after-plone-4-3-upgrade?s=1%7C4.7694

Comment: FTR: Ran in this again, after following Mathias and SteveM. suggestions nothing changed. Unrelatedly cleared my browser's cache'n'cookies and the next time editing, TinyMCE showed up again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plone also stores the chosen editor in the user preferences.
Check `http://yoursite/@@personal-preferences`

There's a small script which migrates all users to tinymce -> http://plone.org/products/tinymce/documentation/how-to/how-to-set-tinymce-as-default-editor-for-current-users/

Comment: +1 might help others. It was usually the reason, if the editor disappeared, whenever I experienced that. However not in this case.

Comment: Oh! Totally fixed my problem. I'll double check with the other content editors of the site, but I think this was it. Odd that it would show up after a month of editing like normal though. Maybe I pulled in some update on a buildout run without noticing. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

4.3 suffers from some random failures loading generic setup profile steps on creating a plone site. There are a few alternative ways to resolve this:

1) Identify the missed steps (in this case TinyMCE) and go to portal_setup and run them. Or, rerun all the steps.

2) Remove or comment out the line "PYTHONHASHSEED random" in base.cfg. Rerun buildout. Restart. Re-add your Plone site.

3) Upgrade to Plone 4.3.1. I haven't heard of anyone having this problem with 4.3.1. If you do, be sure to file a bug report!

Comment: Wished you were true about 3), having the prob with a "Plone 4.3.1 (4306)". Does the number in brackets mean it's actually a 4.3.0.6?   +1 for valuable insights, though.

Comment: Hej, but 1) helped! Gracias :) FTR: Is also described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11152962/954189